# Evaluate $\sin^5 x$ using Imaginary part of $e^{\iota x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

A few days ago somebody posted a problem on evaluating $\int sin^5(x) dx$. The answer posted by Jack D'Aurizio Sir used Complex Numbers to represent $\sin(x)$. This lead to me trying to think of a way to evaluate

> $$\int \sin^5 x \text{ using } \Im(e^{\iota x}) $$

An example of this method is as follows:

$$\int e^x \cos x \, dx$$
Since $\cos x$ is the real part of $e^{\iota x}$, we know that
$$\int e^x \cos x dx = \Re\int e^x e^{\iota x}\, dx.$$

Is there any way we can evaluate $\int \sin^5 xdx$ using a similar technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2\iota \sin(\theta) = x -\dfrac{1}{x},$$ where $x = e^{\iota \theta}$. Then, 
$$\Rightarrow 2^n \iota^n \sin^n(\theta) = \left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^n $$ 
and expanding the R.H.S yields
$$2^4\sin^5(θ) = \sin(5θ)-5 \sin(3θ)+10 \sin(θ)$$

For integration this should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

We can derive the formula for $\int \sin^5 x\,dx$ using the identities $\sin x = \dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ and $\cos x = \dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ along with the Binomial Theorem as follows:

$\displaystyle\int\sin^5x\,dx$ $= \displaystyle\int\dfrac{(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^5}{(2i)^5}\,dx$  $= \dfrac{1}{32i}\displaystyle\int(e^{i5x}-5e^{i3x}+10e^{ix}-10e^{-ix}+5e^{-i3x}-e^{-i5x})\,dx$

$= \dfrac{1}{32i}\left[\dfrac{1}{5i}e^{i5x}-\dfrac{5}{3i}e^{i3x}+\dfrac{10}{i}e^{ix}+\dfrac{10}{i}e^{ix}-\dfrac{5}{3i}e^{-i3x}+\dfrac{1}{5i}e^{i5x}\right] + C$

$= -\dfrac{1}{160}(e^{i5x}+e^{-i5x}) + \dfrac{5}{96}e^{i3x}+e^{-i3x} - \dfrac{5}{16}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}) + C$

$= -\dfrac{1}{80}\cos 5x + \dfrac{5}{48}\cos 3x -\dfrac{5}{8}\cos x + C$

Comment: Thanks Sir, but I know this method. Actually, I was hoping to be able to evaluate $\int sin^5 x$ using a method (by considering the imaginary part of $e^{\iota x}$) similar to the one used to evaluate $\int e^x \cos(x)dx$